# Extract/ Unnest Arrays from Google Ads BigQuery Data Transfer

Tags: sql, multidimensional-array, google-bigquery, nested-lists, google-ads-api

I am trying to extract the Unnest data contained in JSON Arrays that Google Ads sends via BigQuery Data Transfers. Unfortunately, I am getting stuck in the middle.

**Original Data in a BigQuery Table:**

| CreativeId | ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions |
| --- | --- |
| 487067671679 | [{"assetText":"SearchAds Description Text 1","assetId":12443453594,"pinnedField":"DESCRIPTION_1","assetPerformanceLabel":"PENDING","assetApprovalStatus":"APPROVED"},{"assetText":"SearchAds Description Text 2","assetId":12443453165,"assetPerformanceLabel":"PENDING","assetApprovalStatus":"APPROVED"},{"assetText":"SearchAds Description Text 3","assetId":12443453168,"assetPerformanceLabel":"PENDING","assetApprovalStatus":"APPROVED"},{"assetText":"SearchAds Description Text 4","assetId":12443419160,"assetPerformanceLabel":"PENDING","assetApprovalStatus":"APPROVED"}] |

**Desired Outcome:**

| CreativeId | ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions_assetText | ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions_assetId | ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions_pinnedField | ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions_assetPerformanceLabel | ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions_assetApprovalStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 487067671679 | SearchAds Description Text 1 | 12443453594 | DESCRIPTION_1 | PENDING | APPROVED |
| 487067671679 | SearchAds Description Text 2 | 12443453165 | --- | PENDING | APPROVED |
| 487067671679 | SearchAds Description Text 3 | 12443453168 | --- | PENDING | APPROVED |
| 487067671679 | SearchAds Description Text 4 | 12443419160 | --- | PENDING | APPROVED |

This is the query that got me the closest but is still showing JSON.

```
SELECT
  CreativeId,
  JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions) AS Ads
FROM
  `priXXXXXX.sandbox.Ad_XXXXXXX`
WHERE
  ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions IS NOT NULL
LIMIT
  100
```

The Query should be able to include this condition `ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions IS NOT NULL`

Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select Creativeld, 
  json_extract_scalar(el, '$.assetText') as assetText,
  json_extract_scalar(el, '$.assetId') as assetId,
  json_extract_scalar(el, '$.pinnedField') as pinnedField,
  json_extract_scalar(el, '$.assetPerformanceLabel') as assetPerformanceLabel,
  json_extract_scalar(el, '$.assetApprovalStatus') as assetApprovalStatus
from `priXXXXXX.sandbox.Ad_XXXXXXX`,
unnest(json_extract_array(ResponsiveSearchAdDescriptions, '$')) el
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]